# How to create a database tables automatically from txt in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have to create a database in mysql with a table containing 64 columns. Can they be created automatically from the txt file in the terminal (Ubuntu)?

I attach the link with databse:
https://storage.googleapis.com/gtex_analysis_v8/annotations/GTEx_Analysis_v8_Annotations_SampleAttributesDS.txt

Thanks! :D

Comment: You need to know the structure of the data to create a table for it.

Comment: Your file is TSV. It contains columns names, but does not contain the info about columns datatypes. So you can predict these datatypes only approximately... and you may make a mistake (and this will cause problems in future, for example, you may set string column too short, or numeric column integer whereas it must be decimal, and so on).

Comment: If you have no additional data I recommend you to create temporary structure with all columns of some text type (for example, VARCHAR(255)) and import the data, then try to set definite datatypes (with proper convertions, for example, for datas) looking does the errors/warnings about incorrect converton or data truncation occures.